# Support -v, -vv, -vvv, etc. with getopt in Python

Tags: python

There is a common pattern in some tools supporting `-v`, `-vv`, `-vvv`, etc. parameters, so the verbosity level increases depending on the number of 'v's.

I'm trying to implement something similar in Python with [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html). I have a variable named `VERBOSITY_LEVEL` whose values can be 0, 1, 2, etc. depending on the number of 'v's.

I have this code (simplified):

```
VERBOSITY_LEVEL = 0

try:
    opts, args = getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'v:', [...])
except GetoptError:
    print('wrong parameter')
    sys.exit(1)

for opt, arg in opts:
    ...        
    elif opt == '-v':
        if arg == 'vv':
            VERBOSE_LEVEL = 3
        elif arg == 'v':
            VERBOSE_LEVEL = 2
        elif arg == '':
            VERBOSE_LEVEL = 1
        else:
            print('-v%s is not a valid verbosity option' % arg)
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        ...
```

(Probably the part that checks explicitly for `'vv'` or `'v'` could be optimized but that's not the point here)

This code works nicely for `-vv` and `-vvv` but for `-v` it raises the `GetoptError` exception. This is due to `v:` in `getopt()` as `:` for getops means that the parameter has to have an argument. However, the other way around (i.e. using `v` without `:` in `getopt()`) precluded the cases `-vv` and `-vvv` to work.

Somebody has tried to implement some similar with getopt in Python? Any advice or hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getopt will recognise `-abc` as shorthand for `-a -b -c`, so passing multiple `v`s will appear as though you're just passing the argument `-v` multiple times:

```
>>> args = ["-vvv"]
>>> optlist, args = getopt.getopt(args, "v")
>>> optlist
[('-v', ''), ('-v', ''), ('-v', '')]
```

Note that there shouldn't be a `:` after the `v` - it doesn't take an argument

So if you start verbosity at `0`, you can just increment it every time you encounter a `-v` argument:

```
VERBOSITY_LEVEL = 0

for opt, arg in opts:
    ...        
    elif opt == '-v':
        VERBOSITY_LEVEL += 1
```

However, I would always recommend using the `argparse` module over `getopt`, and it turns out the argparse documentation contains exactly this example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count', default=0)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-vvv'])
Namespace(verbose=3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works nicely! By the moment I'll keep with getops (as a Spanish proverb says: "a known evil is better than an unknown good" :)